# PHP session for login function not working correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, session

I am trying to write a function using session. When user has logged in before, they can directly go to home page and do not need to login. If a user has not logged in before, they need to go to login page to login.
However, my result turns out to be that no matter the login information is correct or not, or if they're already logged in, they will always go to the home page.

```
    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('scheduler_model');

        $userinfos=$this->scheduler_model->get_users();

        if(!$this->session->userdata('login_status')){
            $this->load->view('login/loginform');
            $username=$this->input->post("username");
            $password=$this->input->post("password");
            $infomatch=false;
            foreach($userinfos as $userinfo){
                if($username==$userinfo->username && $password==$userinfo->password){
                    $infomatch=true;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if($infomatch){
                $data['username']=$username;
                $user_data = array(
                    'username'=>$username,
                    'login_status'=>true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                redirect('home',$data);
                //$this->input->set_cookie('123','abc','15');
            // redirect('home');

            }
            elseif (!$username || !$password) {
                echo "Type your username and password to login";
            } else {
                echo "Username or password is incorrect, please try again";
                //$this->load->view('login/loginform');
            } 
        } else {
            //$this->session->setuserdata('username',$username);
            redirect('home');

        }
    }
```

The result indicates that whatever they do, they will always go to the following command:

```
else {
            //$this->session->setuserdata('username',$username);
            redirect('home');

        }
```

if I uncomment `//$this->session->setuserdata('username',$username);` there will be an error message says "call to undefined method"

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot to use an underscore and you need to change the commented line to:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('username',$username);
```

Comment: Hi, it does solve the problem for login. However, when I go to localhost/project/home without logged-in account, it still can go to the home page. My goal is to set that when they're not logged in, the users will redirect to the login page when they try to go to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

From you comment, you need to validate user login session in the hope page or other pages as the case may be.

you can use this approach.

on your views, create a file called validation.php

insert this code.

```
if (isset($this->session->userdata['username'])) {
   // you can set some variables as the case may be.     

    } else {
    header("location: login");
    }
```

then go to your homepage and include this.

```
include('validation.php);
```